# Is there some way to allocate specific memory for data in NUMA?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, linux-kernel, numa

I want to allocate memory among all the nodes' memory within the NUMA in a way that I can control (for example, allocate `a` in `node1`'s memory, allocate `b` in `node2`'s memory, and allocate `c` in node4's memory…).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/set_mempolicy.2.html

Comment: Thank you for this. I have read set_mempolicy's description. It seems like set_mempolicy just provide a way to set a memory policy for a thread, but what I want is a way for memory-management on data level which is similar to malloc family.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you use the `numa_alloc_onnode` function (NUMA policy library) to achieve your goal but such allocations are slow.

But bear in mind that NUMA memory affinity is strongly linked to the executing thread which is running on a core [thread->core->NUMA node]. I believe you know what you are doing.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/numa.3.html